# Why can't I save file in external storage or memory card?

Tags: android, file, android-external-storage

I would like to create a backup file in my memory card but all it does is return a file not found exception. I am specifying the path where the data should be saved. When i choose the Internal storage the file was saved but when i changed it to external storage, it returns me the file not found.

Here are the Screenshots: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BG5xs.png)

```
final Preference prefStoragePath = findPreference("key_storage_path");
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
String pref_storage_path = settings.getString("set_storage_path",null);
startingDir = (pref_storage_path!=null)? pref_storage_path : Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

Preference prefBackupManual = findPreference("key_backup_manual");
final String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
prefBackupManual.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
        createBackupData(startingDir);
        return false;
    }
});

private void createBackupData(String dir){
    String filename = "BackupData.txt";
    String data = resultSet().toString();
    try{
        byte[] sha1hash;
        File myFile =  new File(dir,filename);
        sha1hash = data.getBytes("UTF-8");
        String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(sha1hash, Base64.DEFAULT);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
        fos.write(base64.getBytes());
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "no file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "file not saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }finally {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"File saved in " + dir + "/" + filename ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: are you missing a call to `myFile.createNewFile()` before writing data? Also make sure you have the permission to write external storage

Comment: my problem is the file not saving in external storage but when i change the path to the internal storage it will be saved successfully

Comment: What's the error ?

Comment: The `File` constructor does not create an *actual file* by itself, as far as I can see from your code you are getting a `FileNotFoundException` because you are trying to write data into a file that does not exist.

Comment: I managed to save the txt file in my internal storage but when i tried to change the path directed to external storage, it does not create the file.

Comment: its not an error, i just cant save the file in my external memory

Answer (score 1):

*what is happening?*

you are trying to write data into a file that does not exist, thus a `FileNotFoundException` is thrown. The `File(String, String)` constructor does not create an actual file, you must take care of that by yourself.

*How to fix it?*

Check that your app has declared     `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` in the Manifest. If you are targeting SDK 23 or above you should [check and request that permission at runtime](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

Your save method should look like:

```
private void createBackupData(String dir) {
    String filename = "BackupData.txt";
    String data = resultSet().toString();
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        byte[] sha1hash;
        File myFile = new File(dir, filename);
       //NOTE: your file will be overwritten in case it already exists
        if (myFile.exists() || myFile.createNewFile()) {
            sha1hash = data.getBytes("UTF-8");
            String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(sha1hash, Base64.DEFAULT);
            fos = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
            fos.write(base64.getBytes());
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "File saved in " + dir + File.separator + filename, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "no file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "file not saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } finally {
        if (fos != null)
            try {
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

Note: a better approach is using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()` instead of             `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()`

Comment: what Android version are you testing your app on?

Comment: I have just tested this code on an SDK 23 tablet saving a "test" string - it worked as expected. Double-check that you have the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.

Comment: im using android version 5.1.1 api 22

Comment: please update your question and add the LogCat output you get

Comment: does it save in your external memory card? thats where my problem is because i can save in internal memory and doesnt work in SD card

Comment: `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` will return something like `storage/emulated/0`, `/mnt/sdcard` or similar depending on device. If you can't  save files there most likely you missed to declare the required permission I've mentioned.

Comment: my storage/emulated/0 is the internal directory of my device and i've already added the permission in the manifest file still it deos not save the file in the external storage.